# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String org.springframework.data.relational.repository.query.RelationalEntityInformation.getTableName()'

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using below POM and getting the "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String org.springframework.data.relational.repository.query.RelationalEntityInformation.getTableName()'"

Can some one help with this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.gemini.leave.management</groupId>
    <artifactId>service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>service</name>
    <description>Leave Management</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-spi</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Checking the docs, getTableName returns a SqlIdentifier, not a String. Could you share the code where are calling it? https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/relational/repository/query/RelationalEntityInformation.html#getTableName--

Answer (score 2):

The version of `spring-data-r2dbc` that you are using isn't compatible with the versions of the other Spring Data modules that Spring Boot 2.3.x uses by default.

Spring Boot 2.3 has dependency management and a starter module for Spring Data R2DBC so you can align the versions by using the starter and removing the versions from your pom.

Replace the following three dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>r2dbc-spi</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

With the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

The `spring-data-r2dbc` and `r2dbc-spi` dependencies are both part of the `spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc` dependency that replaces them. The versions are provided by the dependency management in `spring-boot-starter-parent`.

If you have a similar problem in the future using the Explore feature of https://start.spring.io can be useful for figuring out how your pom should look.